# Use Semantic Completion with Tabnine in VsCode

Tags: apex, vs-code, autocomplete

Have any of you tried to use [TabNine Semantic Completion](https://tabnine.com/semantic) with VsCode? I tried to use the configuration below but it always crashes.

Just want to make those three great tools to work smooth (VsCode, SFDX/Apex Language Server, and TabNine).

Got the jar and the instructions from [forcedotcom](https://forcedotcom.github.io/salesforcedx-vscode/articles/apex/language-server#integrate-with-the-apex-language-server).

```
[language.apex]
command = "[fullPath]/java"
args = ["-cp", "[fullpath]/apex-jorje-lsp.jar", "-Ddebug.internal.errors=true", "-Ddebug.semantic.errors=false", "apex.jorje.lsp.ApexLanguageServerLauncher"]
synchronous_triggers = ["."]
synchronous_timeout_ms = 5000
num_server_instances = 1
always_prefer = true
```